# Scrum and Google Docs burndown chart

Tags: scrum

There is a tutorial on how to create a burndown chart for Scrum in the Google Docs application:

http://www.scrumology.net/2011/05/03/how-to-create-a-burndown-chart-in-google-docs/

The problem with it though is, it has only a place to update progress once per sprint but the burndown is supposed to be updated with daily progress, right? How can one modify this chart to be able to put daily progress on it?

I mean to be able to plot two lines (ideal and actual) with data such as (story points 255, velocity 24):

Actual Google Docs document (free to edit):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuPWErnOiLTUdElJVzJZaE5EWEZ2S2xCelF6Z2lzaUE

[image: Sprint Data]

[image: Sprint Chart]

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial is really only showing you how to use a spreadsheet to draw a graph. As you say, in a Scrum project, you are probably more interested in the burndown *within* an iteration, on a daily basis. So simply take their approach and replace Iteration with Day. There's no magic about the name of the column in the spreadsheet.

Comment: The problem I see with it is how to plot Ideal line when you have daily updates. Basically, it comes to this - how to plot two lines based on two different time cycles there.

Comment: You can just add more columns if you want more lines. But I don't really see what you're trying to do. You said you wanted to plot a daily burndown chart. That's all you need to run a sprint, eh?

Comment: I've added an example data (edited question) to make my question clearer. GDocs doesn't draw a line in this case for actual story points (because it has blanks)

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are referencing is very basic and meant to be customized :)

When I coach Scrum teams, I generally (not always) advise within the Sprint to:

1. Burn down on task hours
2. Burn up on story points

That way you can see how you are burning down on hours but balance that with actually completing stories.